# Let $r(z)$ be ROC of power series at $z$ that represents $f$. For $z_0$ and $z_1 \in D_{r(z_0)} (z_0)$, show that $|r(z_1) - r(z_0)| \leq |z_1 - z_0|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function. Denote the
> radius of convergence of the power series about $z\in \Omega $ that
> represents $f$ by $r(z)$.
>
> Fix $z_0\in \Omega$ and let $z_1 \in D_{r(z_0)} (z_0)$. How do I show
> that $|r(z_1) - r(z_0)| \leq |z_1 - z_0| $ ?

I have so far shown that I can choose $s < r(z_0) - |z_1-z_0|$ and that there will exist a power series $\sum b_n (z-z_1)^n$ such that  $f(z) = \sum b_n (z-z_1)^n  \;\; \forall z\in D_s(z_1)$

Hence, we must have $r(z_1) \geq s$ and $ s < r(z_0) - |z_1-z_0|$

Can I use this to arrive at my needed result? I tried hard but am unable to derive the required inequality from this. But I do think that I am missing some manipulation in arriving there. Please help

Comment: I basically want to show that the mapping which maps $z\in \Omega$ to the radius of convergence of the power series representing $f$ at $z$ is continuous mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume $r(z_0) < \infty$ which is equivalent to $r(z_1) < \infty$ as otherwise the problem doesn't make sense.

Consider geometrically the points $z_0=A, z_1=B$ and $C$ a point on $\partial \bar D_{r(z_0)} (z_0)$ where $f$ is not analytic (in the sense that there is no analytic extension around $C$ - if you want $C$ is a singular point of $f$ though it may or may not be isolated) which must exist by the definition of $r(z_0)$ (as otherwise, the radius of convergence of $f$ at $z_0$ would be higher than $r(z_0)$).

Now by defintion $f$ is analytic at every point on the circle centered at $z_1$ of radius $r(z_1)-\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon >0$ so $r(z_1)-\epsilon <|BC|$ hence $r(z_1) \le |BC|$

This immediately implies $r(z_1)-r(z_0) \le |BC|-|AC| \le |AB|=|z_1-z_0|$

Note that we actually didn't use at any point that $z_1$ is inside the disc of convergence of $z_0$, we used just the triangle inequality.
This means that we can switch the roles of $z_0,z_1$ and get the other required inequality:

$r(z_0)-r(z_1) \le |z_1-z_0|$ which allows us to conclude!

(the example of an analytic function with natural boundary the unit circle and $z_0=0$, $z_1$ close to the boundary shows that it may happen that $z_0$ is outside the convergence disc of $z_1$ even if $z_1$ is inside the convergence disc of $z_0$)

Comment: I don't get why $r(z_1) - \epsilon  < |BC|$. I understand that $r(z_1)$ is the supremum of the all radii in which the expansion is valid, but why will a given $|BC|$ be greater than any radius very close but smaller than $r(z_1)$.

Comment: Because $C$ is a singular point for $f$ so $f$ cannot have an expansion at $z_1$ on an open disc that contains $C$; by definition $f$ has an expansion at $z_1$ on any disc of radius $r(z_1)-\epsilon$ so $C$ cannot belong to any such which means that $C$ is farther away from $z_1$ than $r(z_1)-\epsilon$

Comment: So when we say that radius of convergence of power series about $z_0$ is $R$, then we mean that we can choose a point $C$ on the boundary of $D_R(z_0)$ such that for a given $ z_1 \in D_R(z_0) $, if we draw a disk around $z_1$ then that disk must not contain $C$ inside it because otherwise $f$ will become analytic at $C$. Would this be correct?

Comment: yes - that is correct (though the conclusion applies to any $z_1$ in the domain of definition of $f$ not necessarily within the convergence disc of $z_0$)

Comment: Thank you so much. You not only helped me with this problem but also taught me a very crucial concept I was missing from my instructor's notes.

Comment: happy to be of help